# Python Pandas Indexing Dataframe with List of Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, slice

I was trying to figure a better/cleaner way to do something like this

```
single_val = 0.5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 7), columns=list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
df[(df['a']>single_val) & (df['c']>single_val) & (df['f']>single_val)]
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
single_val = 0.5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 7), columns=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
data_cols = ['a','c','f']
df[df[data_cols]>single_val]
```

Can anyone tell me

1) how to make my approach work

2) if it exists, a completely different approach that might be better

3) how to do something a little bit more complex like this:

```
val_1 = 0.5
val_2 = 0.7
val_3 = 0.9
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 7), columns=list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
df[(df['a']>val_1) & (df['c']<=val_2) & (df['f']<val_3)]
```

The problem is that for the actual application, I will need to account for a long list of column names and I don't want to type out conditional expressions individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `all` while taking a subset of your columns in the boolean index.

```
df[(df[['a', 'c', 'f']] > single_val).all(1)]
```

For the second part of your question, assuming you want to use actual Pandas syntax and not some `query` magic I think your approach looks fine.

```
df[(df.a > val_1) & (df.c <= val_2) & (df.f < val_3)]
```

By "`query` magic", I would be referring to doing something like

```
>>> conditions = [('a', '>', '1'), ('c', '<=', '2'), ('f', '<', '3')]
>>> query_s = ' & '.join('({0} {1} @val_{2})'.format(*ops) for ops in conditions)
>>> df.query(query_s)

          a         b         c         d         e         f         g
1  0.838162  0.695019  0.564764  0.510963  0.556313  0.800921  0.698653
```

which I would personally avoid unless I had really good reason to do so.

**Demo**

```
>>> df

          a         b         c         d         e         f         g
0  0.328940  0.411345  0.369318  0.388301  0.213110  0.951961  0.623183
1  0.838162  0.695019  0.564764  0.510963  0.556313  0.800921  0.698653
2  0.507048  0.729398  0.814790  0.968008  0.803806  0.355858  0.987389
3  0.402825  0.615113  0.965653  0.223877  0.537247  0.935251  0.402023
4  0.133080  0.641351  0.539981  0.704075  0.539326  0.778625  0.161530
5  0.916859  0.977980  0.954934  0.146030  0.003589  0.889590  0.071854
6  0.655720  0.836904  0.881695  0.423626  0.732105  0.472120  0.646313
7  0.925715  0.522039  0.107891  0.513302  0.688067  0.909862  0.161232
8  0.444260  0.345057  0.872849  0.859115  0.552067  0.173852  0.826250
9  0.301961  0.090283  0.143682  0.765601  0.398364  0.589366  0.177203

>>> df[(df[['a', 'c', 'f']] > single_val).all(1)]

          a         b         c         d         e         f         g
1  0.838162  0.695019  0.564764  0.510963  0.556313  0.800921  0.698653
5  0.916859  0.977980  0.954934  0.146030  0.003589  0.889590  0.071854

>>> df[(df.a > val_1) & (df.c <= val_2) & (df.f < val_3)]

          a         b         c         d         e         f         g
1  0.838162  0.695019  0.564764  0.510963  0.556313  0.800921  0.698653
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = [df[col] > val for col, val in zip(df.columns, list_of_vals)]
```

will give you a list of boolean values for each column. (Slice `df.columns` as needed, or make a separate list

```
np.sum(ls, axis=0) == len(list_of_vals)
```

will give you a list of bools that you can use to find target rows. (It'll only be true if the sum is the maximum possible -that is, if all the boolean values are true.